# EF Core 3.0 HasQueryFilter not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-3.0

I updated my application from EF Core 2 to EF Core 3. One of the breaking changes is **"LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client"** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client).

So I had to change the following `GlobalQueryFilter`:

```
# EF Core2
public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
{
     .....
     builder.HasQueryFilter(x => CheckMandatorId(x));
}

bool CheckMandatorId(TEntity entity)
{
     if (HttpContextMiddleware.Current != null && HttpContextMiddleware.MandatorId != null)
     {
         return HttpContextMiddleware.MandatorId == entity.MandatorId;
     }

     return true;
}
```

to

```
# EF Core 3
public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
{
    .....
    builder.HasQueryFilter(x =>  CheckMandatorId() == -1 || x.MandatorId == CheckMandatorId());
}

int CheckMandatorId()
{
    return HttpContextMiddleware.MandatorId ?? -1;
}
```

The problem is: In EF Core 2 every time a query was executed the current mandatorId was used for the queryfilter. In Core 3 the used MandatorId is not updated after switching mandators.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I don't want to refactor my whole backend if there's another solution.

Update: 
When I'm setting the mandatorId in Constructor everything works as exspected.

```
public DbContext()
{
      MandatorId = HttpContextMiddleware.MandatorId ?? -1;
}
```

But when I call `HttpContextMiddleware.MandatorId` in `builder.HasQueryFilter` directly, queries are not loading the current value for filtering. Someone knows why this happening? Compiler Optimizations?